# SQL Comparison Operator Python) I can't execute comparison operators to SQL query through python file

Tags: python, sql, comparison, mysql-error-1064

```
sql = "WITH comparing_price AS (SELECT CODE, DATE, OPEN, high, low, close, volume,"\
                "LEAD(OPEN, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY CODE ORDER BY DATE) AS 'd1_open',"\
                "LEAD(OPEN, 2) OVER (PARTITION BY CODE ORDER BY DATE) AS 'd2_open',"\
                "LEAD(OPEN, 3) OVER (PARTITION BY CODE ORDER BY DATE) AS 'd3_open',"\
                "LEAD(high, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY CODE ORDER BY DATE) AS 'd1_high',"\
                "LEAD(high, 2) OVER (PARTITION BY CODE ORDER BY DATE) AS 'd2_high',"\
                "LEAD(high, 3) OVER (PARTITION BY CODE ORDER BY DATE) AS 'd3_high',"\
                "LEAD(high, 4) OVER (PARTITION BY CODE ORDER BY DATE) AS 'd4_high',"\
                "LEAD(low, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY CODE ORDER BY DATE) AS 'd1_low',"\
                "LEAD(low, 2) OVER (PARTITION BY CODE ORDER BY DATE) AS 'd2_low',"\
                "LEAD(low, 3) OVER (PARTITION BY CODE ORDER BY DATE) AS 'd3_low',"\
                "LEAD(close, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY CODE ORDER BY DATE) AS 'd1_close',"\
                "LEAD(close, 2) OVER (PARTITION BY CODE ORDER BY DATE) AS 'd2_close',"\
                "LEAD(close, 3) OVER (PARTITION BY CODE ORDER BY DATE) AS 'd3_close',"\
                "LEAD(volume, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY CODE ORDER BY DATE) AS 'd1_volume',"\
                "LEAD(volume, 2) OVER (PARTITION BY CODE ORDER BY DATE) AS 'd2_volume',"\
                "AVG(close) OVER (PARTITION BY CODE ORDER BY DATE, DATE ROWS BETWEEN 2 preceding AND 2 following) AS 'd2_MA5',"\
                "AVG(close) OVER (PARTITION BY CODE ORDER BY DATE, DATE ROWS BETWEEN 7 preceding AND 2 following) AS 'd2_MA10',"\
                "AVG(close) OVER (PARTITION BY CODE ORDER BY DATE, DATE ROWS BETWEEN 17 preceding AND 2 following) AS 'd2_MA20',"\
                "AVG(close) OVER (PARTITION BY CODE ORDER BY DATE, DATE ROWS BETWEEN 57 preceding AND 2 following) AS 'd2_MA60',"\
                "AVG(close) OVER (PARTITION BY CODE ORDER BY DATE, DATE ROWS BETWEEN 117 preceding AND 2 following) AS 'd2_MA120',"\
                "STD(close) OVER (PARTITION BY CODE ORDER BY DATE, DATE ROWS BETWEEN 17 preceding AND 2 following) AS 'd2_std'"\
            "FROM daily_price)"\
        "SELECT * "\
        "FROM comparing_price"\
        "WHERE "\
            "volume > 1 AND d1_volume > 1 AND d2_volume > 1"
execute(sql)
```

And I get an error message:

```
pymysql.err.ProgrammingError: 
(1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 
'> 1 AND d1_volume > 1 AND d2_volume > 1' at line 1")
```

I think the problem is to do with sending comparison operator by execute(), because when directly running this query in HeidiSQL it works fine. Or is there any other ideas why it may not work?

Comment: Looks like space is missing resulting `comparing_priceWHERE`

Comment: Triple-quoted strings would help you avoid similar mistakes.

Comment: @Koguma . . . In the future, print out the SQL string and try running the actual string.

Comment: Oh my, thank you so much people! It works now! I should've double checked... sorry. I thought it was because i had no knowledge in SQL, but looks like I should double check my grammar. Thank you!!!